Allow span in a link, but without transferring the href attribute to the child element
I have successfully managed to add a span element to the CKEditor using my own plugin. This works without problems and the element can be placed in any other element.
The Problem is: When inserting into an a element, it is split as soon as the span tag is inserted (either by inserting via the plugin or by moving the element) and is not treated as a child element as expected:
<p>
    <a href="URL">This is a </a><span>span element</span><a href="URL"> inside a link.</a>
</p>

However, the element can then be placed within an a tag if I additionally define allowAttributesOf: '$text' in the schema (which allows the element to contain the attribute linkHref). But this is what the result looks like:
<p>
    <a href="URL">This is a <span href="URL">span element</span> inside a link.</a>
</p>

I would expect that the element can be placed in a link without the span element also inheriting the href of the link element, and I get the following output:
<p>
    <a href="URL">This is a <span>span element</span> inside a link.</a>
</p>

I simply don't understand why the element successfully inserted into a link also receives a linkHref attribute and I have no idea how to prevent this.
The problem is that this link can then be edited independently of the enclosing element as a link, which in turn leads to the a tag being split up again.
I would be grateful for any useful advice.
PS: Here is the TYPO3 plugin I am working on and where the problem currently exists: iconpack

Does this work for you?
editor:
  config:
    extraAllowedContent : "a span"


Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, this does not work in this case, as this option no longer exists in CKEditor5. In my current understanding, it is rather due to the model (downcast/upcast) and is possibly even related to the TYPO3 link plugin ...?
